# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock - While loop problems

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm making a program for Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock where the computer plays both players. I'm trying to make the game so that it stops when either player1 or player2 has won four times consecutively.

I tried this using a while loop, but it doesn't seem to be evaluating the conditions of the while loop since the game never ends when I run it. To see what is happening, I have it print out the number for `consecutiveWins` after each round, and the tally of wins is in fact being kept,

The problem is that it just does not terminate when it has reached either 4 or -4.

Can anyone see why this would happen?

Output:

```
Player 1 chooses Spock.

Player 2 chooses scissors.

Spock melts scissors.

Player 1 wins.

-5706

Player 1 chooses lizard.

Player 2 chooses rock.

Rock crushes lizard.

Player 2 wins.

-5705

Player 1 chooses paper.


Player 2 chooses rock.

Paper covers rock.

Player 1 wins.

-5706
```

Here is my code:

```
public class RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock {


private int lastWinner = 0;
public static final int ROCK = 1;
public static final int PAPER = 2;
public static final int SCISSORS = 3;
public static final int LIZARD = 4;
public static final int SPOCK = 5;
public static final int PLAYER1 = 1;
public static final int PLAYER2 = 2;

public void play(int player1, int player2) {


    int consecutiveWins =0;
    while ((consecutiveWins < 4) || (consecutiveWins > -4)) {
        String play1;
        String play2;

        player1 = random();
        player2 = random();
        play1 = convert(player1);
        play2 = convert(player2);

        switch (play1) {
        case "rock": // Player 1 chooses Rock
            System.out.println("Player 1 chooses rock.");
            if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.
\nTie.\n"+consecutiveWins);
            } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.
\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.
\nRock smashes scissors.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.
\nRock crushes lizard.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.
\nSpock vaporizes rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            }
            break;

        case "paper": // Player 1 chooses paper
            System.out.println("Player 1 chooses paper.");
            if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.
\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.
\nTie.\n"+consecutiveWins);
            } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.
\nScissors cut paper.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n" +consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.
\nLizard eats paper.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.
\nPaper disproves Spock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            }
            break;

        case "scissors": // User chooses scissors
            System.out.println("Player 1 chooses scissors.");
            if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.
\nRock smashes scissors.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.
\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.
\nTie.\n"+consecutiveWins);
            } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.
\nRock smashes lizard.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.
\nSpock melts scissors.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            }
            break;

        case "lizard": // User chooses lizard
            System.out.println("Player 1 chooses lizard.");
            if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.
\nRock crushes lizard.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.
\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.
\nRock smashes scissors.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.
\nTie.\n"+consecutiveWins);
            } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.
\nLizard poisons Spock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            }
            break;

        case "spock": // User chooses spock
            System.out.println("Player 1 chooses Spock.");
            if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.
\nSpock evaporates rock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.
\nPaper disproves Spock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.
\nSpock melts scissors.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins++;
            } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.
\nLizard poisons Spock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n"+consecutiveWins);
                consecutiveWins=(consecutiveWins-1);
            } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.
\nTie.\n"+consecutiveWins);
            }
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("There was an error. Please try again.");
            break;
            }
        }
    }
public int random() {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        return random;
    }
public int getLastWinner() {
    return lastWinner;
    }

    // https://gist.github.com/vinothpandian/4216643#file-rpsls-in-java
    public static String convert(int n) {
        switch (n) {
        case 1:
            return "rock";
        case 2:
            return "paper";
    case 3:
        return "scissors";
    case 4:
                return "lizard";
        case 5:
        return "spock";
        default:
        return "Invalid choice";
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a logic issue `(consecutiveWins < 4) || (consecutiveWins > -4)` is always true....

Comment: Thank you @Edward I see it now!

Answer (score 0):

A problem i saw with your code:

```
while ((consecutiveWins < 4) || (consecutiveWins > -4))
```

whenever the consecutive wins becomes 4 the second OR condition is still satisfied and continues to execute. Also let us take the situation when Player 1 has 3 consecutive wins and from then on Player 2 has 4 consecutive wins then doesn't the variable consecutiveWins equal to -1 ? A quick solution to your problem would be to simply hold a variable for each player and verify which reaches 4 first in the while loop.
Just modified your code to what I was implying:

```
   public class RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock {
     private int lastWinner = 0;
     public static final int ROCK = 1;
     public static final int PAPER = 2;
     public static final int SCISSORS = 3;
     public static final int LIZARD = 4;
     public static final int SPOCK = 5;
     public static final int PLAYER1 = 1;
     public static final int PLAYER2 = 2;

    public void play(int player1, int player2) {
     int consecutiveWins1 =0,consecutiveWins2=0;
     while ((consecutiveWins1 < 4) && (consecutiveWins2 < 4)) {
       String play1;
       String play2;

    player1 = random();
    player2 = random();
    play1 = convert(player1);
    play2 = convert(player2);

    switch (play1) {
    case "rock": // Player 1 chooses Rock
        System.out.println("Player 1 chooses rock.");
        if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
        {   consecutiveWins1=0;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.\nTie.\n");
        } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1=0;
            consecutiveWins2++;
        } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.\nRock smashes scissors.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.\nRock crushes lizard.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.\nSpock vaporizes rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1=0;
            consecutiveWins2++;
        }
        break;

    case "paper": // Player 1 chooses paper
        System.out.println("Player 1 chooses paper.");
        if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.\nTie.\n");
            consecutiveWins1=consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.\nScissors cut paper.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.\nLizard eats paper.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++; consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.\nPaper disproves Spock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        }
        break;

    case "scissors": // User chooses scissors
        System.out.println("Player 1 chooses scissors.");
        if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.\nRock smashes scissors.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.\nTie.\n");
            consecutiveWins1=consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.\nRock smashes lizard.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.\nSpock melts scissors.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        }
        break;

    case "lizard": // User chooses lizard
        System.out.println("Player 1 chooses lizard.");
        if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.\nRock crushes lizard.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.\nPaper covers rock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.\nRock smashes scissors.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.\nTie.\n");
            consecutiveWins1=consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.\nLizard poisons Spock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        }
        break;

    case "spock": // User chooses spock
        System.out.println("Player 1 chooses Spock.");
        if ("rock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Rock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses rock.\nSpock evaporates rock.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("paper".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Paper
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses paper.\nPaper disproves Spock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("scissors".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Scissors
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses scissors.\nSpock melts scissors.\nPlayer 1 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins1++;
            consecutiveWins2=0;
        } else if ("lizard".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Lizard
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses lizard.\nLizard poisons Spock.\nPlayer 2 wins.\n");
            consecutiveWins2++;
            consecutiveWins1=0;
        } else if ("spock".equalsIgnoreCase(play2)) // Spock
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 chooses Spock.\nTie.\n");
            consecutiveWins1=consecutiveWins2=0;
        }
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("There was an error. Please try again.");
        break;
        }
    }
}
 public int random() {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    return random;
}
public int getLastWinner() {
return lastWinner;
}

// https://gist.github.com/vinothpandian/4216643#file-rpsls-in-java
public static String convert(int n) {
    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        return "rock";
    case 2:
        return "paper";
case 3:
    return "scissors";
case 4:
            return "lizard";
    case 5:
    return "spock";
    default:
    return "Invalid choice";
}
}

  }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why OR is so hard for me to wrap my head around :)

Comment: The suggestion you made works, but it just counts total wins and not consecutive wins.

Comment: @Tiff I tried my suggestion and it terminates after 4 consecutive wins of any player.